# Discord Bot send message without command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have some code that runs in the background, 24/7, in JavaScript of course. I'd like to set a discord.js bot to output a message if something (like an errror) happens on the code that is constantly running.

How do you send a message to any channel without listening for a messagge? All the tutorials create commands that rely on COMMAND to make the bot "reply" to you. I want the bot to be the one sending the first message, and reading back my response and acting accordingly.

I'm currently using the discord.js node library (https://discord.js.org/).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the list of channels from the channel cache by name, and add an event listener for the [`error` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) to window. When an error is detected, send a message to the [channel](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/frequently-asked-questions.md#channels-and-guilds):

```
var client = new Discord.Client();
var channel = client.channels.get('name', nameOfChannel); // or client.channels.get("the channel id")

window.addEventListener('onError', function(e) {
    channel.send(e.error.message) // or client.sendMessage(channel, e.error.message) in older versions;
});
```

Comment: Do Ineed an EventListener? or can I just client.sendMessage in an if statement for example?

Comment: Also I got this when I ran your code: TypeError: client.sendMessage is not a function

Comment: @GalAppelbaum It should be `channel.sendMessage()`, where `channel` should be your targeted channel, since `client` is the bot itself. And also, it is possible. What Ori Drori is doing here is it makes the bot sends a message first to a targeted channel **only** if an error is detected. You can obviously replace it with some other eventHandlers. (Ex: making it send a message when the bot has logged in OR making it send a message whenever a new user enters a server.)

Comment: Now I'm seeing this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined`. I defined channel as such: `var channel = client.channels.get('name', 'general');` and this is after the `client.login(TOKEN)`. This is so weird :(

Comment: @GalAppelbaum - sorry. I've used an older version, and the API changed somewhat. I've updated the answer to the newer version. The `channel` variable is undefined because the client can't find the channel. Try to search for the channel by id. As Wen Qin said, I've wrapped it inside an error handler, because you wanted to send a message on error. You can invoke it wherever you want.

Comment: Oh damn, I saw you're linking to a different discord library I am using. I should've been more specific I guess, my bad. I'm using https://discord.js.org/
I guess maybe thats why I keep getting the `undefined` error.

Comment: Here's a small code snippet thats super basic but still doesn't work for the same reason (channel is unidentified): https://jsfiddle.net/xv22x6Ls/

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work because it can't require discordjs, so it's unrelated. The *the undefined error* is because it can't find a channel, and it returns `undefined`. Create a new channel, and then try to find it in the channels collection.

Comment: This is SO weird. how can there be nothing in the channels collection if the bot is connected to a server?

Comment: @GalAppelbaum I recommend you do `var channel = client.channels.get('name', nameOfChannel);` in the `onReady` eventhandler. As you know, it takes time to make the bot login into discord. And so until the bot is ready and logged in, trying to do `client.channels...` will always return undefined as you are telling your bot to find a channel even though it is not logged in yet. Hence? Make sure that stuff that requires `client` (or generally the bot) to grab channels, users, etc are always done **after** the bot is ready.

Comment: @WenQin thank you very much for explaining. I was a bit lost, Don't fully graps this bot thing yet. I marked as answer and upvoted you all :)

Comment: @GalAppelbaum - have you succeeded in making it work? What did you need to add/change?

Comment: @OriDrori As Wen mentioned, I needed to wait after the bot was ready. Rookie mistake, I didn't realize that after the `bot.login` part there can be latency between code and connection (which is what the `ready` is for). I'm very new to discord API (and bots in general haha) so it was trial by fire.